# How can I ensure the height of a beamercolorbox without breaking the itemize layout?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, boxes, minipage, beamerposter

I am trying to create a poster using `beamerposter` and I want the heights of the two boxes fixed, so that they align equally. So far I achieved that by using a `minipage` environment with a fixed height. However, I recently realised, that an `itemize` environment inside a `minipage` has a significantly different layout, i.e. the structure hangs is either within the margin (`leftskip`, normal behaviour) or not (starts after `leftskip`, behaviour within the new `minipage`).

How can I ensure the height of a `beamercolorbox` without breaking the normal layout of the `itemize` environment?

```
\begin{filecontents}{beamerthememorikyoto-slide.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthememorikyoto-slide}  
% this style is derived from I6pd2 created by Thomas Deselaers an Philippe Dreuw

\mode<presentation>

\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=blue,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{bg=blue,fg=white}
\setbeamerfont {footline}{size=\large,series=\tt}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=blue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=blue,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=blue}

\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{fg=blue!90}
\setbeamercolor{institute in headline}{fg=blue!80}

\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=blue         ,bg=blue!30!white!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{block body} {fg=blue!70!black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{bg=blue         ,fg=white}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\large,series=\bf}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line foot}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line foot}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line}{bg=red}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  % no navigation on a poster
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]     % enumerated figures, tables 

% Controls heading of the block
\newlength{\boxwidth}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4.5ex,
                         dp=0.5ex,
                         leftskip=0.5em,
                         colsep=1.0ex,
                        ]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}%
    {\insertblocktitle\phantom{Gg}}% phantom because of baseline problem
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,
                         rightskip=1em,
                         colsep=1.0ex,
                         sep=0.5ex,
                         vmode
                        ]{block body}%
    \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \setlength{\boxwidth}{\linewidth}
  \addtolength{\boxwidth}{-\leftskip}
  \addtolength{\boxwidth}{-\rightskip}
  }
% Controls how the block is terminated
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2pt]{lower separation line}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{minipage}\par
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \leavevmode

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \parbox[c]%options
           {0.69\paperwidth}{%
        \vskip6ex
        \raggedleft
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\huge{\inserttitle}}\\[2ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
        \vskip2ex
    }\hfill%
    \parbox[c]%options
           {0.30\paperwidth}{%
        \centering
    \rule{0.8\linewidth}{10ex}
    }
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}\par
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2pt]{upper separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=5ex,dp=0.5ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    credentials\hfill\LaTeX
    \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2pt]{lower separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\mode<all>

% adapt height of imtemize rectangles
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\raisebox{0.12ex}{$\blacktriangleright$}\hskip0.1em}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raisebox{0.12ex}{$\triangleright$}\hskip0.1em}
% equal font sizes for all levels
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\normalsize}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[final]{beamer} 

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{morikyoto-slide}}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a3,scale=2,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{multicol}

\title{\texorpdfstring{%
         complicated title}{% with some markup
     complicated title} % without the markup
       }
\author[short author%
        ]{\texorpdfstring{%
          Author 1,* Author 2,+}{% with indicators
          Author 1,  Author 2, } % without indicators
          }

\institute[univ.%
          ]{\texorpdfstring{%
            *University, +University}{% with ind
             University,  University} % without ind
        }

\date{somewhere, sometime}

\begin{document}
% The contents of the whole poster must fit into one frame
% The header (and footer) of the poster is defined in the style template
\begin{frame}[t]{} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.02\textwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{block}{Foo}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item test 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item test 
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.1\paperheight][c]{\boxwidth} 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item test
    \begin{itemize}
      \item test 
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\end{block}
\columnbreak
\begin{block}{Bar}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item test 
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.1\paperheight][c]{\boxwidth} 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item test
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\end{block}
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of mwe]

Comment: If you are going to use the morikyoto-slide theme you had better honor the \leftskip and \rightskip settings, which itemize does NOT.  In other words, EVERY itemize should be placed inside a minipage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by:

- not using your `\boxwidth` but simply `\textwidth`
- removing an unnecessary `minipage` layer around the whole block
- and not messing with the default lengths of `beamercolorbox`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=blue         ,bg=blue!30!white!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{block body} {fg=blue!70!black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{bg=blue         ,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line}{bg=red}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4.5ex,
                         dp=0.5ex,
                         leftskip=0.5em,
                         colsep=1.0ex,
                        ]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}%
    {\insertblocktitle\phantom{Gg}}% phantom because of baseline problem
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
%                                           leftskip=1em,
%                         rightskip=1em,
%                         colsep=1.0ex,
%                         sep=0.5ex,
%                         vmode,
                        ]{block body}%
    \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  }
% Controls how the block is terminated
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2pt]{lower separation line}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Foo}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item test 
            \begin{itemize}
              \item test 
            \end{itemize}
          \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Bar}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item test 
          \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\vfill

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Foo}
          \begin{minipage}[t][0.2\paperheight][c]{\textwidth} 
            \vskip-\baselineskip
            \begin{itemize}
              \item test
            \begin{itemize}
              \item test 
            \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
          \end{minipage}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Bar}
          \begin{minipage}[t][0.2\paperheight][c]{\textwidth} 
            \vskip-\baselineskip
            \begin{itemize}
              \item test
            \end{itemize}
          \end{minipage}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]